# Use the UIImagePickerController on a iphone simulator

Tags: ios, camera, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery

I have the method, that take photos from gallery or from the camera

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
  UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;

  if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
  } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  }

  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

But when i run it on the simulator, code doesnt work. And it doesnt work in `picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` and `picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`

Is the problem in the simulator or in the code?

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833210/iphone-no-saved-photo-album-created-on-iphone

Comment: Are you using a iPhone simulator or iPad simulator.

Comment: Iphone simulator. i changed 'UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum' to 'UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary' but library is empty, where should add photos, before use them in app

Comment: yes, it's because you're using the simulator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
 if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
        {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        }
        else
        {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        }
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

If you are creating the app for iPad. You will have to present the gallery in a popOver control.

Comment: [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO] - doesnt work, but [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES] is ok. and about sourceType i got the same question. why UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary is empty? how should i add photos before running app

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3/4/5** verison:

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
    picker.sourceType = .camera
}
else {
    picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum // or .photoLibrary
}
```

**Swift 2** version:

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
}
else {
    picker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum // or .PhotoLibrary
}
```

In **simulator**, you **can't** use `cameraCaptureMode` and `showsCameraControls`.

Answer (score 1):

In simulator your picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera wont be called as there is no camera available in simulator. Also its a good practice to check whether the source type is available to avoid crashes.

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
….
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePickerCamera =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePickerCamera.delegate = self;
            imagePickerCamera.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
            imagePickerCamera.allowsEditing = YES;
            imagePickerCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            [self presentViewController:imagePickerCamera  animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

    else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePickerAlbum =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePickerAlbum.delegate = self;
            imagePickerAlbum.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
            imagePickerAlbum.allowsEditing = YES;
            imagePickerAlbum.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

            [self presentViewController:imagePickerAlbum animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Comment: Check this link - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController_Class.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the above answers, but I found this easier. Show a pop up alert if the device doesn't have a camera (like the simulator). Sam code, different usage:

```
//button if to take a photo
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

//checks if device has a camera
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIAlertView *noCameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You don't have a camera for this device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        //shows above alert if there's no camera
        [noCameraAlert show];
    }

    //otherwise, show a modal for taking a photo
    else {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```