# new to objective c: need to understand how class methods work in this situation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

if you look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172918/use-the-uiimagepickercontroller-on-a-iphone-simulator), it presents the following if statement:

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
```

because I am new to Objective C, im not sure how this works. here is what i know:  "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary" is a value in an enum, 
isSourceTypeAvailable is a class method. Unfortunately I dont understand any more... can you provide an explanation on how this works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIImagePickerController** is deal with image resource of iOS device.
There are two way by which iOS app can get image from device's resources.
**1. Photo Library**
**2. Camera**

**UIImagePickerController** has **isSourceTypeAvailable** which is a class method and it takes UIImagePickerControllerSourceType

And that method will return that Photo library or camera is available or not as a **BOOL** value.

So that we can perform tasks if resources are available.

Comment: why doesnt isSourceTypeAvailable have any implimentation ? I mean, I dont see any code within this function

Comment: Well, b'cos its closed source. UIImagePickerContrller is class of UIKitFramework and its complied classes. This is not opensource. You won't see code of any frameworks in iOS SDK mostly.

Comment: thanks , now i understand,  however there is some confusion about how this method works - is sourceType a parameter for this method ?

Comment: No, isSourceTypeAvailable: is name of method. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType is parameter

Comment: are you sure ?? isnt UIImagePickerControllerSourceType  the name of the ENUM ?

Comment: Don't get confuse. You need to improve your basic for objective-c. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType is enum and Its parameter type in isSourceTypeAvailable: method. There are multile values for that enum